# Drop-down menu only works after clicking into the parent page first

Tags: navigation

I am using the Venture theme for Drupal 7.
I have a 'Products' page listed in the main menu with a drop-down list that is a separate page for each product. However, to get the drop-down list to show up, I first have to click on the 'Products' menu link, which will bring me to an empty page.

I would like the drop-down list to display if I hover over the 'Products' menu item so the user can select a child product page right away instead of having to go into the parent 'Products' page first and then having the option to select from the drop down menu like it is doing now..
Ideally, I would like to not have to display the parent 'Products' page at all, and have it just be in the main menu as a way to access the drop-down list items to other pages.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the "show as expanded" for the parent menu?

Edit your parent level menu and see if it's checked.

Check it if it's not and check the drop down menu again.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a specific theme or a custom one?

It seems to be an issue with incorrect classes being applied to the parent list-item element.

While on the main page for my Drupal website, inspecting the list-item element that I know has a dropdown within it shows me:

`<li class="first collapsed">`

The .collapsed class makes sense since I'm not hovering over it, but even hovering over it does not append the .expanded class that I would expect.

When navigating to the parent page that has the dropdown within it and inspecting the same element, I now see:

`<li class="first expanded active-trail">`

And now if I hover over the list-item, the dropdown list appears as expected. Therefore, it's likely that the culprit is either the `.expanded` or `.active-trail` class, or both.

In order to remedy this we could try using a little JavaScript to always give list-items with a `ul` within them the `.expanded` and `.active-trail` classes.

I apologize if this is too technical. I could provide a walkthrough if you'd like. Keep in mind that this is only my best guess based on my own experience with this problem. I haven't yet tried my own solution.